# How can I implement pagination with Sendgrid API?

Tags: python, pagination, sendgrid

I'm trying to fetch a list of all customers that have unsubscribed our services using [SendGrid API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/requests.html). With this request I'm only receiving the first 50 customers, so I figured I would have to work with pagination. Unfortunately nothing I do seems to work at the moment, could someone help me?

This is my code that gets only 50 results (the first 50 emails):

```py
import sendgrid
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key='API_KEY')
response = sg.client._("asm/suppressions").get().body.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

After a few tries I managed to get the pagination right with this simple line of code:

```
data = {'limit': 30000, 'offset': 0}
response = sg.client._("asm/suppressions").get(query_params=data)
```

SendGrid's API is not very clear, so I hope it can help others. You can tailor the limit based on how many emails you need to retrieve. I'm my case was around 25000, hence data limit = 30000.